# display array if have same value in some key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, maps

i have some array of object like this

```
var data = [
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-14","dateEnd":"2020-04-15","location":"Chicago"},
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-16","dateEnd":"2020-04-17","location":"Chicago"},
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-20","dateEnd":"2020-04-29","location":"Miami"},
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-24","dateEnd":"2020-04-28","location":"Philly"}
]
```

i want to achieve if location have same value, in this case chicago, 
then return new array with merging dateStart and dateEnd

the dateStart from first object that have location chicago, and the dateEnd taken from the second object that have location chicago

```
var data = [
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-14","dateEnd":"2020-04-17","location":"Chicago"},
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-20","dateEnd":"2020-04-29","location":"Miami"},
    {"dateStart":"2020-04-24","dateEnd":"2020-04-28","location":"Philly"}
]
```

i hope clear enough

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` function to do that.

```js
var data = [ {"dateStart":"2020-04-14","dateEnd":"2020-04-15","location":"Chicago"}, {"dateStart":"2020-04-16","dateEnd":"2020-04-17","location":"Chicago"}, {"dateStart":"2020-04-20","dateEnd":"2020-04-29","location":"Miami"}, {"dateStart":"2020-04-24","dateEnd":"2020-04-28","location":"Philly"}]

var result = data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    index = acc.findIndex(val=>val.location == elem.location);
    if(index != -1){
        acc[index].dateEnd = elem.dateEnd;
    } else {
        acc.push(elem);
    }
    return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```